# Force github pages to use _site folder

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a github pages website. I need to use the jekyll-pagniation-v2 gem, but github pages only support v1. Thus I'm compiling the site locally and pusing up the entire `_site` directory to my github repo.

My understanding is that it should use what I've pushed in the `_site` dir, which looks fine locally. When I view the live site the index page doesn't contain any of the posts. As if it tried to rebuild the site and failed to find any posts because it's using the wrong pagination version.

How can I ensure github pages is not rebuulding the site and is using the version of the site I pushed to `_site`

Comment: Can you provide an example? Or a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that it wasn't actually pushing changes to the right branch and i'm an idiot.